# pagination and reusing views in scrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, pagination, lazy-loading

I have to show around 100pages in a scroll view and each page contains 8 image views and 8 labels..images of image view should be loaded lazily. the sample i created loads the images lazily and pagination is also fine but i am loading all the 100pages with each page containing   8 image views and 8 labels altogether..it works fine on simulator but i have not tested it on device as i am scared to see it crashing as i am loading so many views at a time. Can anyone help me or guide me to some sample which can help me reusing my views as well as i can perform lazy loading of imageviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the post [UIScrollView and lazy loading](http://favo.asia/2010/06/uiscrollview-and-lazy-loading/), describing how to do lazy loading of images in `UIScrollView`.

This is exactly the kind of step-by-step intro to lazy loading with `UIScrollView` that you are looking for.

The idea is: you keep, e.g., 3 views in memory: the current, the previous one, and the next one; so you can move to the next one or previous one with  no delay. When you move to one new view, you load the previous one and the next one (if necessary). If you plan on having fast scroll as an important feature, you would need to increase the number of views in memory to 5 or 7. The more views you hold in memory, the seamless scrolling will be, but you will pay a price in terms of memory usage.

I would not suggest trying to keep all the views in memory because the device memory will fill up and your app will be killed. In any case, you can try and see if the device can handle all those views in memory at the same time.

One interesting option you might consider is showing an activity indicator while a page is being loaded. This would make scrolling feel more natural, although the view shall be loaded.

Having a look at your files, one thing I noticed is the

```
for (int i =0; i<loopTimes; i++)
```

in `loadImagesForPage`.

You might try to split that method so that it's not executed on a single run (blocking the UI meanwhile). I mean:

```
for (int i =0; i<loopTimes; i++) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadSingleImageForPage:)
               withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]
               afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

where `loadSingleImageForPage:` is a method which encapsulates the current body of the for loop. By doing like this (i.e., using the `afterDelay`) you load one page and return back to the run loop; then the next one and return back to the run loop; etc. When you return back to the run loop, you give the system a chance to deal with the UI, delegate calls, whatever...

I hope this could make a difference. Otherwise, my suggestion is just trying to comment out portions of your code (i.e., checking whether the app work correctly when displaying only the placeholders without attempting to download the images, etc.).

EDIT (7/9/2013)

Since the link above seems to be dead, here is the code:

**1 - Listen for scrollViewDidScroll on your delegate, like this:**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView {
}
```

**2 - Calculate the current page using the known size of your images:**

```
/**
 *  calculate the current page that is shown
 *  you can also use myScrollview.frame.size.height if your image is the exact size of your scrollview
 */
int currentPage = (myScrollView.contentOffset.y / currentImageSize.height);
```

**3 - Look if the image already exists, if not, add it:**

```
// display the image and maybe +/-1 for a smoother scrolling
// but be sure to check if the image already exists, you can do this very easily using tags
if ( [myScrollView viewWithTag:(currentPage +1)] ) {
    return;
}
else {
    // view is missing, create it and set its tag to currentPage+1
}
```

**4 - And don’t forget to clean your memory:**

```
/**
 *  using your paging numbers as tag, you can also clean the UIScrollView
 *  from no longer needed views to get your memory back
 *  remove all image views except -1 and +1 of the currently drawn page
 */
for ( int i = 0; i < currentPages; i++ ) {
    if ( (i < (currentPage-1) || i > (currentPage+1)) && [myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] ) {
        [[myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**5 - And the final combination of all steps:**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView {

    int currentPage = (myScrollView.contentOffset.y / currentImageSize.height);

    if ( [myScrollView viewWithTag:(currentPage +1)] ) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        // view is missing, create it and set its tag to currentPage+1
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < currentPages; i++ ) {
        if ( (i < (currentPage-1) || i > (currentPage+1)) && [myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] ) {
            [[myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] removeFromSuperview];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it helped me..but m facing problem on device if i create view on scrolling time...firstly scroll is not so smooth...and secondly f i try to scroll too fast,views come blank....i guess i have to load all the views alotgether

Comment: yes i have tried it,if i increase number of views to 5,then after scrolling one page,scrolling stays disabled for few moment..maybe cuz its in a state of creating and deleting views.hmm m struck,..its been 3 days already..:( and also..if i keep 5 views in memory then also very fast scrolling results in blank views. Please keep me update if you find anything more helpful and thanks for your help uptil now

Comment: you say: "maybe cuz its in a state of creating and deleting views..." could you open a new question and post the code you are using to create and delete those views? the issue might be there...

Comment: can i send you my class?? cuz code is really mixed up, i may miss some important part which may be causing trouble, you can look  into my class whenever you get time and tell me if you could figure out something from it??

Comment: send it (you can find my address on my website, accessible from my profile), but if it's mixed up, well, I am not sure I can find out anything...

Comment: i cant find you address on your website..i tried to search before also..:( and its not that mixed up...but little too mixed up for posting here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18768/discussion-between-ivishal-and-sergio)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend `UIPageViewController`, [this is a good tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application) how to implement it.

So the idea is you have one controller to show all your images and labels on the page, so when you go to the next page you just start another controller and set images, also you remove previous page from memory. Every page is represented by an instance of your page controller and UIPageViewController is in charge. You don't have to do page curl animation if you don't want to.

Of course you can calculate position of every item on the page in the scroll view and move items and load other images by using pagination of `UIScrollView`, but if you have hundreds of pages, why not to use `UIPageViewController`?

By the way, you don't even need a tutorial, you can just create `Page Based Application` from iOS templates and then move your code to `Model Controller` and `DataViewController`

Comment: What you described requires much refactoring while in fact is the same  as creating the next view only when required, isn't it ?

Comment: sure, it does require refactoring, but as for me it would make code much simple. So one instance of controller represents any page, and the pageViewController just changes pages. Plus as bonus you might have nice animations.

Comment: Alright, that's true. You also linked a guide as requester, and I don't think it will be easy to find the guide of lazy views loading as that is kind of lazy-loading basics.

Answer (score 0):

Sor some others, you can have a look into my class available at [VSScroller](https://github.com/iVishal/VSScroller.git)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple UIScrollView subclass that like UITableView implement cell reusability, the project [MMHorizontalListView](https://github.com/manuelemaggi/MMHorizontalListView) is on gitHub, there is also a test project, so you can see how to use it with an example, it works also with old iOS versions like 4.x (probably even older...)